# PercentCompleteEditor allows values > 100 in bwu_datagrid

Tags: dart, bwu-datagrid

PercentCompleteEditor allows to enter values > 100 and < 0 without any error/warning in bwu_datagrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These editors are only examples to demonstrate how you can build your custom editors. I'll create an issue and fix it anyway. Thanks for reporting. https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_datagrid/issues/115